# how to add or embed CKEditor in php page

Tags: php, ckeditor

how to add or embed CKEditor in php page, I downloaded and extracted the zip file into root of the directory and also called on my page

```
<?php require("ckeditor/ckeditor.php"); ?>
```

gave the textarea this fields

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor1">Write any thing</textarea>
```

But its not working,
Documentation for installation on PHP is not found CKEditor website.

Does any one knows where we or help me out..for this app.

Comment: What's wrong with using javascript? CKEditor is client side, what will php do?

Comment: then i need to work on with javascripts -> php.., i would like to do it php itself. And if we do in javascripts, how do we can the ckeditor through javascripts.

Comment: That's in the docs, did you looked at them? there's even a full detailed API section

Comment: CKEditor5 can configure as here https://www.ebhor.com/php-ckeditor-installation-and-uses/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Easy steps to Integrate ckeditor with php pages

step 1 : download the ckeditor.zip file

step 2 : paste ckeditor.zip file on root directory of the site or
you can paste it where the files are (i did this one )

step 3 : extract the ckeditor.zip file

step 4 : open the desired php page you want to integrate with here page1.php

step 5 : add some javascript first below, this is to call elements of ckeditor and styling and css
without this you will only a blank textarea

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

And if you are using in other sites, then use relative links for that here is one below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="somedirectory/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

step 6 : now!, you need to call the work code of ckeditor on your page page1.php
below is how you call it

```
<?php

// Make sure you are using a correct path here.
include_once 'ckeditor/ckeditor.php';

$ckeditor = new CKEditor();
$ckeditor->basePath = '/ckeditor/';
$ckeditor->config['filebrowserBrowseUrl'] = '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html';
$ckeditor->config['filebrowserImageBrowseUrl'] = '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images';
$ckeditor->config['filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl'] = '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash';
$ckeditor->config['filebrowserUploadUrl'] = '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files';
$ckeditor->config['filebrowserImageUploadUrl'] = '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images';
$ckeditor->config['filebrowserFlashUploadUrl'] = '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash';
$ckeditor->editor('CKEditor1');

?>
```

step 7 : what ever you name you want, you can name to it ckeditor by changing the step 6 code last line

```
$ckeditor->editor('mycustomname');
```

step 8 : Open-up the page1.php, see it, use it, share it and Enjoy because we all love Open Source.

Thanks

Comment: Here they have not mentioned about adding javascript. http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/PHP/CKEditor_Integration#Manual_Integration

Comment: `ckeditor.php` is no longer included in CKEditor 4. You should either copy `*.php` files from CKEditor 3.x... or (better solution): learn on how to use JavaScript to include a JavaScript component on your website. Using JavaScript you get access to new features offered by CKEditor 4 like inline editing.

Answer (score 16):

If you have downloaded the latest Version 4.3.4 then just follow these steps.

- Download the package, unzip and place in your web directory or root folder.
- Provide the read write permissions to that folder (preferably Ubuntu machines )
- Create view page test.php
- Paste the below mentioned code it should work fine.

Load the mentioned js file

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
> <textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor"></textarea>
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Alternately, it could also be done as:

```
<?php
    include("ckeditor/ckeditor.php");
    $CKeditor = new CKeditor();
    $CKeditor->BasePath = 'ckeditor/';
    $CKeditor->editor('editor1');
?>
```

Note that the last line is having 'editor1' as name, it could be changed as per your requirement.

Comment: Use 4 spaces to indend block of code instead of doing crazy things with html ;)

Answer (score 3):

no need to require the ckeditor.php, because CKEditor will not processed by PHP...

you need just following the _samples directory and see what they do.

just need to include ckeditor.js by  html tag, and do some configuration in javascript.

Comment: ckeditor.php is a utility class to use CKEditor from PHP without the need to bother about the html and javascript.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php require("ckeditor/ckeditor.php"); ?>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="somedirectory/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor1"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

After reading the [Quick Start Guide](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/quick-start.html)

> In your HTML page add an element that CKEditor should replace:

```
<textarea name="content" id="editor"></textarea>
```

> Load the classic editor build (here CDN location is used):

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/10.0.1/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

> Call the ClassicEditor.create() method.

```
<script>
    ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        } );
</script>
```

---

> Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CKEditor 5 - Classic editor</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/10.0.1/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Classic editor</h1>
    <textarea name="content" id="editor">
        <p>This is some sample content.</p>
    </textarea>
    <script>
        ClassicEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
            .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
            } );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**This example is for the specific classic editor. FOr other variants, only CDN will change.**