# CKEditor in Twig Template + Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, ckeditor, twig

I want to use CK Editor in my Symfony 2 project. I downloaded the zip file, unzipped and put it in my js folder, I included it in the page where I want the Editor. I am following  this Question [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151889/how-to-add-or-embed-ckeditor-in-php-page) now I am stuck at step 6. How can I include that php in my twig template.

The php that is in step 6 that needs to be included is

```
<?php

// Make sure you are using a correct path here.
include_once 'ckeditor/ckeditor.php';

$ckeditor = new CKEditor();
$ckeditor->basePath = '/ckeditor/';
$ckeditor->config['filebrowserBrowseUrl'] = '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html';
$ckeditor->config['filebrowserImageBrowseUrl'] = '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images';
$ckeditor->config['filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl'] = '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash';
$ckeditor->config['filebrowserUploadUrl'] = '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files';
$ckeditor->config['filebrowserImageUploadUrl'] = '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images';
$ckeditor->config['filebrowserFlashUploadUrl'] = '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash';
$ckeditor->editor('CKEditor1');
```

?>

Can I replace the name with any variable that contains the html and i pass it from my controller to view ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CKEditor only requires HTML and Javascript. The PHP files are simply for use as utility helpers to emit the proper HTML and Javascript.

Just include the link to the `ckeditor.js` file and insert a textarea with the `ckeditor` class in your twig template. *(I also found that I needed an id tag, but it didn't matter what it's value was)* CKEditor will handle the rest.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple CKEditor Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the example you quoted, they are also using the [CKFinder](http://ckfinder.com/) file manager. It *does* require PHP in order to handle the file manager functions. Integration instructions for that item are beyond the scope of your original question.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a form type

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class CkeditorType extends AbstractType
{
  public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
      'attr' => array('class' => 'ckeditor')
    ));
  }

  public function getParent()
  {
    return 'textarea';
  }

  public function getName()
  {
    return 'ckeditor';
  }
}
```

add this to your service

```
services:
    ckeditor:
        class: Bundle\myBundle\Form\Type\CkeditorType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: ckeditor }
```

and use it un form like this

```
->add('myfield', 'ckeditor')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a bundle for this feature ? There's [plenty of it](http://knpbundles.com/search?q=ckeditor) !

I've tried [TrsteelCkeditorBundle](https://github.com/trsteel88/TrsteelCkeditorBundle) and it works quite well ! Easy setup and configuration.