# I have Problems with Ckeditor in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

in my template i have:

```
<form>
  <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
    This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
  </textarea>
  <script>
    // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
    // instance, using default configuration.
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', { toolbar : [ ['Bold','Italic','Font','FontSize'] ] });
  </script>
</form>
```

and the result is this:

> localhost/PeopleSymfony/web/app_dev.php/index/config.js?t=G4CD Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
>       7391ff2_ckeditor_5.js:85 
>       GET http://localhost/PeopleSymfony/web/app_dev.php/index/lang/es.js?t=G4CD http://localhost/PeopleSymfony/web/app_dev.php/index/skins/moono/

i dont know to how solve.
i did php app/console assets:install to reinstalle assets but have the same error

**why  search es.js in 
//localhost/PeopleSymfony/web/app_dev.php/index/lang/es.js?t=G4CD and no in the bundle ivoryckeditor?**

Comment: Try reinstalling your web assets. This error just means it couldn't find the web-assets

Comment: i did php app/console assets:install but have the same errors

Comment: also dump your assetics : php app/console assetic:dump

Comment: can you show the `<script>` and `<link>` tags loading the JS ad CSS?

Comment: i did php php app/console assetic:dump  but have the same errors

Comment: Why, for goodness sake, why do you have a javascript with php inside? This is simply wrong, as your javascript must work without php (and php must work without javascript). The only point where javascript meet your code is in html

Comment: @MassimilianoArione Placing `PHP` inside a `javascript` script block (inside the html, not in an external resource) isn't that uncommon...

Comment: i did this example but i have the same errores http://stackoverflow.com/a/12962518/6496534