# Configuring CKeditor 4.0

Tags: php, ckeditor

I am trying to configure CKeditor4.0 on my website. But unfortunately I am unable to configure it properly. I tried the steps exactly as mentioned [in this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151889/how-to-add-or-embed-ckeditor-in-php-page).

But I am getting an error message like

```
Warning: include_once(ckeditor/ckeditor.php) [function.include-once]:
failed to open stream:
```

When I tried to find the ckeditor.php file in the ckeditor directory, I could not find it.

Comment: Well, if it's not there, then where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That file should be there. If it is not there, your copy is corrupt. Download the files again from ckeditor's site.

Comment: I downloaded from "http://ckeditor.com/download". And still unable to find the ckeditor.php file.

Comment: What other files are there in the that folder?

Comment: ckeditor.js, config.js, build-config.js and few css file.

Comment: Ok.. I just checked. That download does not have any php related files. May be, they have removed PHP based integration and PHP users can use javascript to print the editor. I did not find the PHP related downloads either.

Comment: The tutorial that you are looking at is for older version which had PHP integration. You should look at the tutorials at ckeditor's site for integrating ckeditor 4.