# textarea element with HTML editing bar

Tags: html, textarea, styling

I was looking for a way to implement a text area element in HTML or PHP, where you can enter text and apply styles to it like bold, italick , highlight and color etc.

Something like the one i am typing this question into. Can someone please suggest something.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on this : http://ckeditor.com/

i used it before and its really good.

Here is another post of how to use it : [how to add or embed CKEditor in php page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151889/how-to-add-or-embed-ckeditor-in-php-page)

Answer (score 0):

This is called a rich text editor, some browser do have a built in one, but you can have them from libraries as well.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_rich-text_editor

Comment: thanks .. this really describes it ..... "RICH TEXT EDITOR", thats what i want to implement