# simple blog posting without using CMSs

Tags: php, forms, textarea, rich-text-editor

I have a page for my blog in my website. I don't really need a CMS to install because I am not going to use all the features. I just need to have a rich text editor on the back-end in my "post news" and just fill it in with the latest news about what I am going to do. And in the blog page (that is just a PHP page to get data from the DB) I have it in a nice format with all news I have posted.

I tried to use some rich text editors on top of a textarea field but in my data base it saves it as one line without any break or bold etc.

I know that the data has to be saved in the database as:

```
"Hello,<br>I want to inform you all that today is my <b>BirthDay</b><br>..."
```

But is there any rich text editor that when I submit my form it submits my textarea data with the html tags?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:JavaScript-based_HTML_editors

Comment: Also, `<b>` is deprecated in favour of `<strong>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest solution is - integration of CKEditor in your application.

Here is an useful link -

[how to add or embed CKEditor in php page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151889/how-to-add-or-embed-ckeditor-in-php-page)

CKEditor has more documentation and examples on web for complex issues like document templates changing and other known bugs and it has proven itself over the past 7-8 years.

Comment: So why do **you** think CKEditor is better than TinyMCE, YUUI, etc etc?

Comment: CKEditor has more documentation and examples in web for complex issues like document templates changing and other known bugs and it has proven result for last 7-8 years. Previous Version was FCKEditor , which was also very popular for saving rich text contents.