# how to integrate CKEditor 4 in php page

Tags: ckeditor

How to integrate CKEditor 4 in php page? I looked at similar topics such as [how to add or embed CKEditor in php page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151889/how-to-add-or-embed-ckeditor-in-php-page), but when I extracted the zip file there is no file called *ckeditor.php*.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there's no PHP connector for CKEditor v4 as some features are still waiting to be ported from v3. Some people reported successful integration of v3 connector into v4 so you can always give it a try and use the code from the [latest 3.6.x package](http://ckeditor.com/download).

See the [post on the form](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor/What-happened-to-PHP-integration) to know more.

Answer (score 0):

Sample form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>A Simple Page with CKEditor</title>
    <!-- Make sure the path to CKEditor is correct. -->
    <script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
            This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
        </textarea>
        <script>
            // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
            // instance, using default configuration.
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```